# DOM not updating on GET request + data-attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Issue: Upon updating the src of images, retrieved via GET request, the DOM never updates but their new values show in console.

Suspected Cause: I think there is some conflict with using data-attributes, but using attr() instead of data() does not seem to remedy.

**HTML to be updated:**

```
<div class="data-block">
    <img data-item="hp-logo" />
    <img data-item="hp-banner" />
</div>
```

**GET Request:**

```
if(promoid != null) {       
    $.get({
        url: '/snippets/data.html',
        cache: false
    }).then(function(data){
        var tempData = $('<output>').append($.parseHTML(data)).find('.data[data-promo-id="' + promoid + '"]');
        myContent = tempData.html();
        dataItems = $('.data-block').html();
        //console.log('Data Items On Page: ', dataItems);
        $(dataItems).each(function (index, value) {
            if( $(this).is('[data-item]')) {
                //console.log('Data Items With Attribute: ', this);
                dataItemLookup = $(this).attr('data-item');
                //console.log('Data Item Lookup Value: ', dataItemLookup);
                $(myContent).each(function (index, value) {
                    //console.log('Retrieved Items Checking Against: ', this);
                    if ( $(this).attr('data-alias') == lastalias ) {
                        //console.log('Retrieved Items Match Alias: ', this);
                        if ($(this).attr('data-item') == dataItemLookup) {
                            //console.log('Retrieved Item Match', this);
                            dataImageDesktop = $(this).attr('data-image-desktop');
                            //console.log('Value to be Passed to Data Item: ', dataImageDesktop);
                        } else {
                            // Do nothing
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Do nothing
                    }
                });
                $(this).attr('src', dataImageDesktop);
                console.log(this);
            }
        });
    }); 
}
```

**data.html:**

```
<div class="data-container">
    <div class="data" data-promo-id="11202016">
        <div data-alias="test.html" data-item="hp-logo" data-image-desktop="http://placehold.it/250x150"></div>
        <div data-alias="test.html" data-item="hp-banner" data-image-desktop="http://placehold.it/350x250"></div>
        <div data-alias="not-test.html" data-item="hp-spot" data-image-desktop="http://placehold.it/450x350"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Not sure how to proceed in troubleshooting this issue. Everything works as expected, except the DOM updating. Ideas?

Comment: why are you try to do each in string?  here // $('.data-block').html();

Comment: They may show up in multiple locations on page and in multiple contexts, so I need to check if they have a data-item attribute and then conditionally if they match an alias or not.

Comment: may you show the full source?

Comment: If I understand correctly.. $('.data-block').html(); is retrieving innerHtml. Then $(dataItems).each()  is looping through those. How am I creating new ones?

Comment: hehehe, hey guys, calm down please. I have an another question: why the variable lastalias is undefined in your source code?

Comment: Thanks Randy and Tablar. That completely escaped me. Working like a charm now. If one of you put it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @RandyStivenValentín, above this code I'm grabbing the page alias from the URL and setting as a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `html()` on an element will get you the innerHTML of the object, which is a string.  As such using it inside $() later will cause jQuery to create new elements that are not attached to the DOM.  If all you are after is to select elements and modify them, simply use the $(selector) and modify it.  Do not use html() and wrap the results with $().

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$(selector).attr('data-name')` try using `$(selector).data('name')` as shown in the [jQuery.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) documentation.